# Spark "replacing null with 0" performance comparison

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql

Spark 1.6.1, Scala api.

For a dataframe, I need to replace all null value of a certain column with 0.
I have 2 ways to do this.
1.

```
myDF.withColumn("pipConfidence", when($"mycol".isNull, 0).otherwise($"mycol"))
```

2.

```
myDF.na.fill(0, Seq("mycol"))
```

Are they essentially the same or one way is preferred?

Thank you!

Answer (score 18, accepted):

They are not the same but performance should be similar. `na.fill` uses `coalesce` but it replaces `NaN` and `NULLs`, not only `NULLS`.

```scala
val y = when($"x" === 0, $"x".cast("double")).when($"x" === 1, lit(null)).otherwise(lit("NaN").cast("double"))
val df = spark.range(0, 3).toDF("x").withColumn("y", y)

df.withColumn("y", when($"y".isNull, 0.0).otherwise($"y")).show()
df.na.fill(0.0, Seq("y")).show()
```